# Wasserstein, Constant Speed Geodesic, Optimal Transport Map. Ambrosio Lemma 7.2.1. Disintegration.

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, optimal-transport

I'm reading Lemma 7.2.1 of Ambrosio Gradient Flows in Metric Spaces 2nd edition.

On the top of page 159 we have

\begin{align*}
W_p(\mu_0,\mu_1)\leq& \Big( \int_{X\times X} \|x_1-x_3\|^p d\mu(x_1,x_3) \Big)^{1/p}
\\
\leq& ...?
\\
=&\Big(\int_{X\times X} \|x_1-x_2\|^p d\gamma(x_1,x_2) \Big)^{1/p}+\Big(\int_{X\times X} \|x_2-x_3\|^p d\eta(x_2,x_3) \Big)^{1/p}
\\
=& W_p(\mu_0,\mu_t)+W_p(\mu_t,\mu_1)
\\
=& tW_p(\mu_0,\mu_1)+(1-t)W_p(\mu_0,\mu_1)=W_p(\mu_0,\mu_1).
\end{align*}

But I cant fill in the blanks in the line of argument, to be honest I don't understand the notation $\|x_1-x_3\|_{L^p(\mu,X)}$ I would read this as the Lp norm of function $x_1$ but obviously it doesn't mean this. Can someone explain the reasoning?

Answer (score 1):

This is a shortcut for 
$\|f_1-f_3\|_{L^p(\mu,X)}$ with $f_1(x_1,x_3)=x_1$ and $f_3(x_1,x_3)=x_3$.

Comment: Ah sure so its how I interpreted it in my working. Could you explain the missing lines of working?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the "$\le\dots$" part, that's because of the triangle inequality of the norm.